# /usr/bin/ld: ../freeglut/libfreeglut_static.a(freeglut_state.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes' in make of Box2d

Tags: linux, cmake, box2d, x11

I followed [this](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/setup-linux) and it showed me steps for installing.
I have dependencies previously installed.
`unzip Box2D_v2.1.2.zip
cd Box2D_v2.1.2/Box2D/Build
cmake ..
make`

At the last step of make I got the following message.
`/usr/bin/ld: ../freeglut/libfreeglut_static.a(freeglut_state.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
I searched online everyone said to compile with `-X11`flag but this a make file and i dont much abou that

Comment: Please edit your question to include OS name and version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the `CMakeLists.txt` file in `Testbed` is not configured for Linux.

To fix this, open the file `Box2D_v2.1.2/Box2D/Testbed/CMakeLists.txt` and change the following lines accordingly.

From this:

```
if(APPLE)
         # We are not using the Apple's framework version, but X11's
         include_directories( /usr/X11/include )
         link_directories( /usr/X11/lib )
         set (OPENGL_LIBRARIES GL GLU GLUT X11)
endif(APPLE)
```

To this:

```
if(UNIX)
        # We are not using the Apple's framework version, but X11's
        include_directories( /usr/X11/include )
        link_directories( /usr/X11/lib )
        set (OPENGL_LIBRARIES GL GLU X11)
endif(UNIX)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Build example, box2d_2.3.1 : Old software, "older" compiler is used ...

```
tar xvf box2d_2.3.1+ds.orig.tar.xz
cd box2d-2.3.1/Box2D/
mkdir build && cd build/
CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 cmake -DBOX2D_INSTALL=ON -DBOX2D_BUILD_SHARED=ON -DBOX2D_BUILD_STATIC=ON -DBOX2D_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ../
make
.
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libBox2D.so
[100%] Built target Box2D_shared
```

Link, box2d_2.3.1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/box2d/box2d_2.3.1+ds.orig.tar.xz

**Note** : Works as well with the year 2010 version `Box2D_v2.1.2` https://code.google.com/archive/p/box2d/downloads